# PancakeSwap API to get lists of new tokens

Tags: graphql, pancakeswap

I want to get lists of all the new coins listed over the pancakeSwap so which API I should use? or do I need to use contract to get the lists of new coins?

I tried using Pairs and tokens API from PancakeSwap document(https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-info-api/blob/develop/v2-documentation.md) and also subgraph api of pairs but request is keep failing with 500 status code. Can anyone please help me with this issue or is there any other solutions to get lists of new coins over pancakeSwap?

Thank you!